# Setting alpha of ColorDrawable does not work

Tags: android, kotlin, alpha, colordrawable

I am trying to achieve an effect in my app of where the user scrolls down, the opacity of a view will change from 0 to 1.

To achieve this, I've created a ColorDrawable with my desired color, blue, and then set its alpha to 0.

```
val actionBarBackground = ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(it, R.color.myBlue))
(activity as? AppCompatActivity)?.supportActionBar?.setBackgroundDrawable(actionBarBackground)
```

However, after increasing the alpha, it does not change. I've tried printing the value of actionBarBackground but its still 0...

```
// This is called inside a scrollview callback that calculates an alpha value between 0 and 255
actionBarBackground.alpha = 255
Log.d(TAG, "Alpha: ${actionBarBackground.alpha}") // Prints: Alpha: 0
```

Any ideas why the alpha of the `ColorDwarable` does not change? Thank you.

Comment: It might be nice if you add the **tag** for the *language* you are using (***presumably Kotlin*** ?). See [ColorDrawable setAlpha](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable#setAlpha(int)).

Comment: Thank you @JonGoodwin I've added the Kotlin tag. I've read the documentation of multiple times, and the `.setAlpha()` function does not seem to change the value in the color drawable.

Comment: See *kotlin docs.* [mutate](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable.html#mutate) and [invalidateself](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable#invalidateself) and [setAlpha](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable.html#setalpha). This looks WRONG in your question`actionBarBackground.alpha = 255` something *like* `actionBarBackground.setAlpha(255)` ?

Comment: Thnk you Jon. In kotlin, getters and setters are automatically transformed into properties, so `.setAlpha(255)` in kotlin is just `.alpha = 255`. Even Android Studio suggests this change, when you use the normal setAlpha. However, you were right about `.mutate()`. Using it, and replacing my ColorDrawable with the mutated Drawable returned, the alpha change works fine. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Jon Goodwin's comment, I finally fixed the problem.

For some reason, changing the alpha value on a `ColorDrawable` in Kotlin, does not seem to have any effect (it used to work in Java).

However, replacing this `ColorDrawable` with the `Drawable` you get from calling `.mutate()` on the `ColorDrawable`, makes the alpha changes work.

My final, working code from my question:

```
val actionBarBackground = ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(it, R.color.myBlue)).mutate()
// Keep in mind that actionBarBackground now is a Drawable, not a ColorDrawable
(activity as? AppCompatActivity)?.supportActionBar?.setBackgroundDrawable(actionBarBackground)

actionBarBackground.alpha = 255
Log.d(TAG, "Alpha: ${actionBarBackground.alpha}") // Prints: Alpha: 255
// This also works when called form inside a ScrolView Listener, to fade the actionbar background.
```

P.S.: Also check his detailed answer on why this happens in Kotlin.

Comment: Glad to help ;O)

Answer (score 1):

I guess I should answer, as Lucas P. says:

> However, replacing this `ColorDrawable` with the `Drawable` you get from
>   calling .mutate() on the `ColorDrawable`, makes the alpha changes work.

But it is **not** for some *reason*, there is **a** **reason**:

> mutate() added in API level 3
>
> open fun mutate(): Drawable
>
> A mutable BitmapDrawable still shares its Bitmap with any other
>   Drawable that comes from the same resource.

```
mutate()
Added in API level 3

public Drawable mutate ()
```

> Make this drawable mutable. This operation cannot be reversed. A
>   mutable drawable is guaranteed to not share its state with any other
>   drawable. This is especially useful when you need to modify properties
>   of drawables loaded from resources. By default, all drawables
>   instances loaded from the same resource share a common state; if you
>   modify the state of one instance, all the other instances will receive
>   the same modification. Calling this method on a mutable Drawable will
>   have no effect.

[reference mutate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#mutate())

Kotlin distinguishes between mutable and immutable collections, automatically --cool (if you know what that means).

> An immutable class is a class whose state cannot be changed once it
>   has been created.
>   [Mutability](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/learning-to-use-and-abuse-mutability-b4c71576299)

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation! Also the article on Mutability was a great read!